# How do I invoke the same directive multiple times on the same element?

Tags: angularjs

Here is the entirety of my program

```
<body ng-app="xx">
<p cl-x="1" cl-x="2"></p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js">
</script>
<script>
angular.module('xx', function() {})
.directive('clX', function() {
  return {
   link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(attrs.clX);
    }
  };
});
</script></body>
```

What I would like it to do is print out on the console 1, then 2.

What it in fact does is just print out 1.

Some options that are **not** open to me are

- putting both arguments in a single invocation: `<p cl-x="1,2"></p>`
- putting the two invocations in different elements: `<p cl-x="1"><span cl-x="2"/></p>`

Automatic downvote for anyone who tries to convince me I can do what I cannot do.

Comment: Both are same attributes, how do you expect `cl-x` to be of both the instances. You can consider looking at the 2 options in your questions, i guess. even if you do cl-x and data-cl-x, it will render twice but the attribute value will just be one

Comment: You are right, but that isn't the problem -- I don't see "1" logged twice.  I guess once I get both invocations to "fire", then I will need to find a way to get and distinguish the attributes.

Comment: why cant you make it element restricted (or even class restricted) and put them in separate attributes? so you can just read all the attributes on it, regardless of the attr name. But i really would like to know why do you need it that way.. :)

Comment: Well you should get both invocations to fire if you use cl-x and data-cl-x. <p cl-x="1" data-cl-x="2"></p>. But do an element[0].outerHTML and see whether you see them both, my guess would be you will only see the first occurance of attribute. **[W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0) --> `There must never be two or more attributes on the same start tag whose names are an ASCII case-insensitive match for each other.`**

Comment: @PSL :) i was busy searching the spec for that. A parser would simply skip the second attribute or overwrite the first value. So identical attributes will never work. I got it to fire 4 times ;) '<test class="test: 1;" test="2" data-test="3"></test>' but in the end the attribute.test returned by pre/post link compile always returns 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PSL points out, attributes may not repeat.

Given, the constraints you have supplied (that it must be on a single element and you cannot parse the multiple arguments from a single attribute) you can can only use the different alias mechanisms that AngularJS provides (data-*, etc.) AND use different node types (element, class, attribute, comment). You could successfully invoke the same directive on the same element multiple times but each invocation will appear differently in the markup.

Such code would be obtuse and and confusing but achieves your objectives within your constraints.

Comment: Well, [we're boned](http://suptg.thisisnotatrueending.com/archive/17543409/images/1326597528329.jpg).